# What is the syntax for passing values to a struct within a contract written in fi?

Tags: smart-contracts, fi

I have defined a type `Poll` using a struct.
I would like to be able to instantiate it, preferably passing initial values to its variables when I do.
eg I would imagine a syntax for what I want to do something like:

`let Poll poll = new Poll ({cost : mutez 100});`

or
`let Poll poll = (cost : mutez 100);`

The best I can do right now is to instantiate an empty default of each type in storage and then initialise them with a contract call, which seems a little ugly, as well as being an unnecessary cost.

```
storage Poll defPoll;

entry initateTypes(Poll defPoll){
  storage.defPoll = input.defPoll
}

entry newPoll(string url, mutez cost){
  let Poll poll = storage.defPoll;
  poll.owner = SENDER;
  poll.payer = SENDER;
  poll.cost = input.cost;

  storage.polls.push(input.url, poll);
}
```

Comment: Just as a warning: i am not sure FI is actively maintained any more (the latest commit is 11 months ago on the fi github). I would use either SmartPy or LIGO as actively developped and maintained high level languages for tezos for mainnet deployment

Comment: Could you show the full code of your contract? Where is Poll defined? You mention structs, but I see no mention of structs in the fi manual.

Comment: Thanks for that info - I was not aware of this and thought that FI was new!

(BTW the Poll could be any struct, in this case, having a single member, `cost`. structs are on the front page of https://learn.fi-code.com/ and compile fine)